# jQuery sticky footer doesn't appear to be sticking

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a portfolio site here:

mrliger.com

When i change pages occasionally the footer will pop up for a split second instead of sticking to the bottom of the page. I have having a look at various sticky footers i have chosen to go for this jQuery sticky footer:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/jquery-sticky-footer/

here is my code below:

```
<body class="lazy" data-original="bgfinal2.jpg">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400' rel='stylesheet'     type='text/css'>

<!--<div class="backgroundimage"></div>-->

<div class="loadingpage"></div>

<div class="header">
<div class="centreheader">
<img src="images/logome.png" class="logo">
<img src="images/mobile-menu-icon.png" class="mobile-menu-icon">
<div class="navhide">
      <ul class="header-options">
            <div class="headercurrent"><div class="arrow-up"></div></div>
            <a><li class="homebutton">Home<div class="icon" style="background-image: url(home.png)"></div></li></a>

            <a><li class="aboutbutton">About<div class="icon" style="background-image: url(about.png)"></div></li></a>

            <a><li class="portfoliobutton">Portfolio<div class="icon" style="background-image: url(portfolio.png)"></div></li></a>

            <a><li class="musicbutton">Music<div class="icon" style="background-image: url(music.png)"></div></li></a>

            <a><li class="contactbutton">Contact<div class="icon" style="background-image: url(contact.png)"></div></li></a>
        </ul>
      </div>    
</div>
<div class="topnavi"></div>

    </div>



<div class="home">
    <div class="homecontainer">

</div>
</div>

<div class="about">
    <div class="aboutcontainer">

<div class="pagetitle">about</div>

<img class="profilepic" src="bg2.jpg" />



<div class="textbreak"></div>

<div class="textbox">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>


</div></div>

<div class="portfolio">
    <div class="portfoliocontainer">


<script>





</script>

<div class="pagetitle bump">portfolio</div>

<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/arcade-2.png)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Betfair - Arcade</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/live-dealer.png)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Betfair - Live Casino</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>


<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/footie-leaderboard.png)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Betfair - Arcade</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/vip-2.png)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Betfair - VIP</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>

<!--
<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/tradefair.png)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Betfair - Tradefair</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>
-->

<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/your-world.png)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Your World Recruitment</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/poker-acq.png)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Betfair - Poker</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/casino.png)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Betfair - Casino</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/roulette.png)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Betfair - Casino</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/arcade.png)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Betfair - Arcade</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>



<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom lazy" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/free-bet-fever.png)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Betfair - Arcade (old brand)</div>
</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>





<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/blackjack.jpg)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Betfair - Casino</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>

<!--

<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/tradefair-2.png)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Betfair - Tradefair</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>

-->

<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/vip.png)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Betfair - VIP</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="portfoliopod portfolioimagezoom" style="background-image:url(http://mrliger.com/images/jan-blues.png)">
<div class="portfoliopodmessagetop">+</div>
<div class="portfoliopodmessage">Betfair - Arcade (old brand)</div>
<div class="portfolio-back">&lt;&lt; back</div>
</div>
<div class="portfoliotextbox ">

</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="music">
    <div class="musiccontainer">


<div class="pagetitle">music</div>

<div class="textbox">In my spare time I like to produce electronic music. Growing up I have always had a strong musical background and have played a range of instruments. My influences over the past few years have mainly come from the Deep house scene and I am always looking out for new artists and genres coming out. If you're interested have a listen to some of my latest creations below</div>

<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/161223881&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
<div class="textbreakmusic"></div>

<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/137200377&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
<div class="textbreakmusic"></div>

<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/133553657&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>





</div></div>

<div class="contact">
    <div class="contactcontainer">

<div class="pagetitle">contact</div>

<div class="textbox">If you like what you see (and hear) feel free to get in touch with me and discuss any future projects we could work together on</div>

<div class="mycontactform">



<form name="myForm" action="form_process.php" method="POST"> 



<label for="field_name">Name:</label> 

<input type="text" id="field_name" name="sender_name"> 

<br /><br />   

<label for="field_email">E-mail:</label> 

<input type="text" id="field_email" name="sender_email"> 

<br /><br />   

<label for="field_phone">Phone:</label> 

<input type="text" id="field_phone" name="sender_phone"> 

<br /><br />   

<label class="bumpleft"for="field_message">Message:</label> 



<textarea id="field_message" name="sender_message"></textarea> 

<br /><br /> 
<br /><br />  


 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LfU1P0SAAAAALHISZktklS0s_WdRhdq2r6QvU10"></script>

    <noscript>
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LfU1P0SAAAAALHISZktklS0s_WdRhdq2r6QvU10" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
    </noscript>

<input class="sendbutton" type="submit" name="send_message" value="Send"> 

</form>

</div>






</div></div>

<div class="footer" id="footer"></div>





</body>
```

Any ideas why its not sticking? jQuery and its sticky footer plugin are both included in the header.

Comment: So do you mean in some instances it doesn't stick to the bottom at all or when loading the page it will 'jump' very quickly from the top to bottom?

Comment: so basically when clicking on another section of the page for example going from "music" to "portfolio" it will flash at the top of the page for a few seconds. Might take you a couple of tries to replicate the issue...

Comment: But it does get to the bottom eventually? That sounds like the CSS having not been applied first and then loading it on the element. So it takes time to load the CSS and apply it to the element I mean.

Comment: yes eventually it does, what im trying to prevent is it appearing for a split second at the top as it doesnt look good and is quite noticable. I assumed the jQuery sticky footer would ALWAYS keep it at the bottom no matter what

Comment: Guess `<a>` is trying to refresh the page.

Comment: I now look at your website and see that the page doesn't refresh when clicking on the menu items. When you load the next page there is no content to push the element to the bottom first, and after the content is loaded it will appear at the bottom. Or do I misinterpret the issue?

Comment: thats spot on @Bastiaan hence why i assumed the jQuery plugin would always push it down

Comment: So if you want the element to always be placed at the bottom you would need to have some content (or margins) which push the element to the bottom. I mean that when you load the other content you would need "empty content" to push the element to the bottom while the other page loads.

Comment: I think your missing the point of this plugin. Its supposed to keep the footer at the bottom of the page regardless of what content lies between it and the header..

Comment: remove jQuery.noConflict()

Comment: Ill try that soon, but i dont see how it will help my issue...

Comment: That worked @dm4web however the sticky footer follows me whereever i scroll which is not exactly what i was after, i just want it to stay at the very bottom of th page. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @BenLiger remove pace.start() [see](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/)  . for footer add id="footer".

Answer (score 0):

Can I request you to check the console of client browser? As I can see your stickyfooter.js have some errors. Maybe resolving this error can help you more.

```
SCRIPT5009: 'pace' is undefined 
mrliger.com, line 13 character 1
SCRIPT5007: Object expected 
stickyfooter.js, line 2 character 1
```

Comment: That could be it, if its failing on line two would that suggest that $ from jQuery has not yet been defined?

Comment: It means your library is not imported .

Comment: Sorry could you expand on that please

Comment: Seems you have removes the footer plugin. Also, as suggested by @dm4web, add id="footer". Please let me know one this is done. I will try to figure out why your jQuery library is failing to load.

Comment: Why do you require pace.start(). I can't see the pace working for your page. Also, it is giving error on pace!